# Change View of Sharepoint XSLT List View webpart in javascript

Tags: sharepoint-2013, office365-apps

I have created a Sharepoint hosted app for Office 365. It has a page file "default.aspx". I have added an XSLTListViewWebpart on that page, referring a custom List I created within my APP project. I have a requirement that on a button click event, I need to change the View of the List displayed in the XSLTListViewWebpart. Since there is no server code within the APP, would this be possible in javascript? Or would it be possible to somehow change the query that the webpart uses?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Javascript object model to achieve this. Please see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185010%28v=office.14%29.aspx) article.

Comment: Thanks for that. However the documentation in the link provided is not very specific to my situation. I am a beginner and could use a lot more detail. Do you have an alternate way to achieve this or is there an alternative webpart I could use?

Comment: I put some thoughts in your problem and i'm thinking - what do you need to change XsltViewWebPart part view dynamically when you click button? You can easily redirect to view when you click on a button.

Comment: Redirecting to a view would not be a solution, as there are multiple buttons on the page and each need to display a new view in the one xslt webpart next to them. This would be very easily possible on server side code, refer this [link](http://spblog.net/post/2011/04/26/Changing-default-view-for-ListViewWebPart-programmatically.aspx). Im looking for a javascript equivalent of this.

Comment: Yes, i agree it is easy to achieve using server object model. Also i was working with XsltListView web part not so long ago and there is some functionality of providing parameters for web part using query string. Try to provide query string parameter View={ViewId} where ViewId is view guid. I'm not sure if this will work but i think it worth a try.